# refineslide change var on click

Tags: jquery, initialization, onchange, var

I'm using a plugin and though it functions perfectly I can't get the var the change on click. Is there a proper way to get the transition attribute to change on click from 'cubeH' to 'cubeV'?

```
var direction ='cubeH'

$('.rs-prev').click(function(){
    direction ='cubeV'
});

$('.rs-slider').refineSlide({
    transition : direction
});
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution from within the plugin. Has the same intentions as I did here is the final code:

```
,prev: function () {
            if (this.settings.transition === 'custom') {
                this.nextAnimIndex--;
            }

            // If on first slide, loop round to final slide
            if (this.currentPlace == 0) {
                this.settings.transition =('cubeV')
                this.transition(this.totalSlides - 1, false); // Call transition
            } 
            else if (this.currentPlace == 2) {
                this.settings.transition =('cubeH')
                this.transition(this.totalSlides - 3, false); // Call transition
            }
        }
```